# Formatting output using ToString

Tags: c#, format, output, tostring

I am trying to edit my Fuel Consumed line in C# to output the word "gallons" after the numeric quantity. I am not sure how to manipulate ToString to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    // toString method to display object information
    public override string ToString()
        {  return "\n\nDestination: " + destinationCity +
                "\n\nTotal Miles: " + mileageRoundTrip.ToString("F0") +
                "\n\nFuel Consumed: " + gallonsUsed.ToString("F1") +
                "\n\nFuel Cost Per Gallon: " + gallonsCost.ToString("C") +
                "\n\nTotal Fuel Cost for this Trip: " + totalFuelCost.ToString("C") +
                "\n\nMPG: " + amountMPG.ToString("F0") +
                "\n\nFuel Cost Per Mile: " + costPerMile.ToString("C"); }
```

Comment: What is the issues that you facing now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similarly to the concatenation that you are already preforming, you can insert another string literal surrounded by plus `+` operators after the variable but before any newline characters, this will place the unit of measurement after the numerical value. For example:

```
+ " gallons" +
```

**Edit:**
GreagoryABeamer made some good points in his post for adding adding a robust, systematic implementation of a printed unit. My solution isn't that and if this is at all production or repeated code, that is a much better answer. This solution, however, does present the opportunity for quick use and non-existent overhead (I believe that string literals are concatenated at compile time in c# as well as c++). The code can also look very clean with some aligning of the variables and literals. Perhaps haskish, but sometimes I prefer the quick simplicity. :)

Comment: Works, but it exacerbates the creation of additional strings to return a different string view of the object and still uses an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to keep your original format including two newline characters, this should do it in a more memory-efficient way while giving you the desired "gallons" suffix.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("\n\nDestination: {0}", destinationCity);
sb.AppendFormat("\n\nTotal Miles: {0:F0}", mileageRoundTrip);
sb.AppendFormat("\n\nFuel Consumed: {0:F1} gallons", gallonsUsed);
sb.AppendFormat("\n\nFuel Cost Per Gallon: {0:C}", gallonsCost);
sb.AppendFormat("\n\nTotal Fuel Cost for this Trip: {0:C}", totalFuelCost);
sb.AppendFormat("\n\nMPG: {0}", amountMPG);
sb.AppendFormat("\n\nFuel Cost Per Mile: {0:C}", costPerMile);
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: This is the best solution. Very readable since the code lines match up with output lines, and formatting code is minimised. Thank you @Mvarta for extending my knowledge! :)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you really want ToString() to work in this method, you should be using a StringBuilder instead of concantenating. No, concats won't slow things down that much, but you are creating a lot of extra strings behind the scenes to get what you want.

As for adding, you can do something like so:

```
public override string ToString()
{  var builder = new StringBuilder();
   /// more lines here
   builder.Append(gallonCost.ToString("C"));
   builder.Append(" gallons\n\n");
   // etc
   return builder.ToString();
}
```

You can also create internal helper methods for each item to format it how you want and then just concatenate them in the builder. It is cleaner.

But, from an architectural standpoint, there are a lot of smells in this way of doing things. The reason for altering ToString() is to change a representation of the object from default, not to format information for the user interface. If that is the motivation, you are better to do this via a second object and avoid the smell, unless you are making a rule all objects act the same way (still not great, but consistency is easier to follow).

If this is a one-off or temporary app, you might get away with it. If it is personal, it is your own business, so do what you want. For Enterprise software, I would tag this in a code review and force someone to let me know why they used this particular pattern, as it is non-standard and likely against best practices.

Answer (score 1):

**Update: See @mvarta's answer which combines format with a StringBuilder for a more readable solution.**

I find `String.format()` more readable because you write the entire template as one string:

```
return String.format(
    "\n\nDestination: {0}\n\nTotal Miles: {1:F0}\n\nFuel Consumed: {2:F1} gallons\n\nFuel Cost Per Gallon: {3:C}\n\nTotal Fuel Cost for this Trip: {4:C}\n\nMPG: {5:F0}\n\nFuel Cost Per Mile: {6:C}", 
    destinationCity, 
    mileageRoundTrip, 
    gallonsUsed, 
    gallonsCost, 
    totalFuelCost, 
    amounts, 
    costPerMile
);
```

To add gallons where ever you want, you simple write it there in the template.

Variables are represented in your template with `{0}`, `{1}`, etc. where the number is the position of the variable in the following parameters.

All your specific formats in your toString calls are also embedded into the template using `{0:C}`, `{1:F1}`, etc. `string.Format()` is calling `toString()` for you so it's less verbose.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx